# PostgreSQL 11 - Procedure support

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

- PostgreSql Version : 11 Beta 4
- Npgsql Version : v4.0.3

I want to test Store Prodecure of PostgreSql, but I get the error.

```
"42809: get_customer_list() is a procedure"
```

My CommandType

```
CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Does Npgsql support PostgreSql 11 Store Prodecure ?

Answer (score 6):

Please see [this answer in the Npgsql FAQ](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/faq.html#stored_procedures).

Long story short, you can call stored procedures but not with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Simply make a regular command with the text `CALL my_stored_procedure()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I developed a data layer that supports 4 databases (MsSql, Postgresql, MySql, Oracle) with a single code. I had to use "CommandType.StoredProcedure" for writing the single code. So far I was using "Functions" but not using the "Out" parameter with "Functions". I would like to use the "Stored Prodecure" functions that come with PostgreSql 11 instead.

Comment: The other problem I wrote is that the stored procedure result set does not return data. Only the message is coming
"CALL
Query returned successfully in 136 msec.

My Procedure 
`
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Customer_List()
 AS $$
   SELECT * FROM public."Customer";
   $$
LANGUAGE SQL;`

Comment: As far as I know, procedures can't return anything (at least not at this point). Functions do support so-called out variables and can be used without problem, so you may not need stored procedures.

Comment: Yes, but cannot be used with setof or table. I think this can be done with the Stored Procedure.

For example :
"
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_func
(
 OUT total_count integer
)
RETURNS SETOF "Manufacturer" 
 AS $$

total_count :=  100;

SELECT * FROM public."Manufacturer";

$$  LANGUAGE sql;
"
"ERROR:  function result type must be integer because of OUT parameters
SQL state: 42P13"

Comment: So again, *functions* support returning stuff, as well as out variables (which are just another way of specifying what the function returns). AFAIK the new *procedures* don't support either, and even if they do, Npgsql won't support processing them (at least at this point).

Comment: @KorkutDüzay - You *CAN* return setof in a function -- you just can't combine it with an OUT parameter, the way you listed.